# Separating a nested function

Tags: javascript

I’m working on my own plugin. It generates table divs and chair divs and groups the chairs to the table divs. Creating chairs is done in a function inside the table function, but that's not good practice as plugins are usually containing separate functions.

I want to make the chairs optional though, meaning the code will work fine and report no errors. But I can’t place the chairs function outside of the table function and get no errors. I’m probably going about it the wrong way I feel? What do I need to change?

```
    function createTables() {
    var availableTables = [],
        newTable, tableProp;
    for (var i = 0; i < defaultSettings.numberofTables; i++) {
        newTable = $('<div id="table' + i + '"></div').css({ 'width': defaultSettings.tableSize.tableW + '%', 'height': defaultSettings.tableSize.tableH + '%', 'background-color': 'black' });

        tableProp = { 'left': defaultSettings.tablePos.posX + '%', 'top': defaultSettings.tablePos.posY + '%', 'position': 'absolute', 'display': 'none' };
        var availableSeats = [],
            newSeat, seatProp;
        var horPosArr = new Array(0, 5, 10);
        var seatPosX, seatPosY;

        function createSeats() {
            for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                if (j < 3) {
                    seatPosX = defaultSettings.tablePos.posX + horPosArr[j];
                    seatPosY = defaultSettings.tablePos.posY + 14;
                } else {
                    seatPosX = defaultSettings.tablePos.posX + horPosArr[j - 3];
                    seatPosY = defaultSettings.tablePos.posY - 4.5;
                }

                newSeat = $('<div class="seat' + i + '"></div').css({ 'width': defaultSettings.seatSize.seatW, 'height': defaultSettings.seatSize.seatH, 'background-color': 'white', 'border': 'solid black 2px' });
                seatProp = { 'left': seatPosX + 0.5 + '%', 'top': seatPosY + '%', 'position': 'absolute', 'display': 'none' };
                newSeat.css(seatProp).appendTo('body').fadeIn(defaultSettings.speed);
                availableSeats.push(newSeat);
            }
            return availableSeats;
        }
        availableSeats = createSeats();
```

Also, is there anything else I should do with a modular approach? Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1u7zhe3p/1/).

Comment: I don't think there's a situation where nested function are relevant. You could make another function instead, which would take parameters

Comment: The inner function uses variables from the outer function. Pass those (like `horPosArr`) as arguments to the new function that you can place outside of `createTables`.

Comment: I'm still learning this stuff too, but here's one way to think about this: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/hjeu6n9o/  - this could also be a good candidate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  // otherwise - you should probably break the question down a bit further into parts with more simple examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the seats to be optional, add a `seats` property to your settings. I might pull out the createSeats function like this.

```
function createSeats(tablePos) {
  var availableSeats = [] 
  var seatPosX, seatPosY;
  var horPosArr = new Array(0, 5, 10);
  for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    if (j < 3) {
      seatPosX = defaultSettings.tablePos.posX + horPosArr[j];
      seatPosY = defaultSettings.tablePos.posY + 14;
    } else {
      seatPosX = defaultSettings.tablePos.posX + horPosArr[j - 3];
      seatPosY = defaultSettings.tablePos.posY - 4.5;
    }

    var newSeat = $('<div class="seat' + tablePos + '"></div').css({ 'width': defaultSettings.seatSize.seatW, 'height': defaultSettings.seatSize.seatH, 'background-color': 'white', 'border': 'solid black 2px' });
    var seatProp = { 'left': seatPosX + 0.5 + '%', 'top': seatPosY + '%', 'position': 'absolute', 'display': 'none' };
    newSeat.css(seatProp).appendTo('body').fadeIn(defaultSettings.speed);
    availableSeats.push(newSeat);
  }
  return availableSeats;
}
```

And modify createTables to be

```
function createTables() {
  var availableTables = [],
      newTable, tableProp;
  for (var i = 0; i < defaultSettings.numberofTables; i++) {
    newTable = $('<div id="table' + i + '"></div').css({ 'width': defaultSettings.tableSize.tableW + '%', 'height': defaultSettings.tableSize.tableH + '%', 'background-color': 'black' });

    tableProp = { 'left': defaultSettings.tablePos.posX + '%', 'top': defaultSettings.tablePos.posY + '%', 'position': 'absolute', 'display': 'none' };

    if (defaultSettings.seats)
      createSeats(i);

    if (defaultSettings.tablePos.posX >= 60) {
      defaultSettings.tablePos.posX = 17, defaultSettings.tablePos.posY += 30;
    } else { defaultSettings.tablePos.posX += 18; }
    newTable.css(tableProp).appendTo('body').fadeIn(defaultSettings.speed);
    availableTables.push(newTable);
  }
  return availableTables;
}
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1u7zhe3p/4/).

I agree with one of your commenters that if you want to ask how this should be structured, it's probably a better question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: After your answer, I changed the classes of each seat so they all have their own and not just the same class as the other seat divs in the array. I wanted to give them each their own class like so:`<div class="table' + i + 'seat' + tablePos + '"></div>` So i could target each seat belonging to a specific class like so: `<div class="table1seat1"></div>` I need the `i` integer for that that loops in the tables function. How do I pass that to the seats function?

Comment: @Zhyohzhy tablePos *is* i from the createTables method. It's already passed.